# Load Jenkins into a DR environment

Tags: jenkins

I've been looking all over the internet for a free way to load Jenkins up as an enterprise application. To be more clear, I mean to load Jenkins front end into two or more servers and allow load balancing between them.

Everything I've read is regarding distributed build. While I will also want to do this, make all servers build agents as well, I would like a disaster recovery environment kind of set up for the front end in the event that, say, our connection is down to a data center. Active/Active hosting would be desired, but active/backup would be fine too.

Any materials available to explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this solution but it looks like the [Gearman Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gearman+Plugin) might provide the architecture you're looking for.  It looks like the plugin creates a job queue that can be accessed by multiple Jenkins masters and serviced by multiple build agents.  Looks like this would support an active/active set up.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gearman+Plugin

Comment: I'd like to keep the software contained within plugins of Jenkins without having to run another server. Additionally, not sure how this would fix the lack of information between the two masters. I'm going to leave the answer open for now, but this may be the best option available without extensive changes to Jenkin's core code... which Cloudbee's probably already did.